# Analyse Equicontinuity (uniform continuity) of a function $ \frac{\sin(x)}{x},\; x > 0 $

Tags: calculus, continuity, equicontinuity

How can I analyse equicontinuity of the function $$
\frac{\sin(x)}{x},\; x > 0?
$$

When I draw the graph it is clear that this function is equicontinous, but I can not prove it analytically.
Tried to prove using definition. I am stuck.
Any hints or better ways to do this kind of problems?

Comment: By "equicontinuous", do you mean "uniformly continuous"? If that is the case, you can try proving that the function is actually Lipschitz continuous, because its derivative is bounded.

Comment: I am preparing for an exam and we didn't cover Lipschitz continuity yet. I am not allowed to use

Comment: Well, whatever, you can try showing that your function $f=f(x)$ is uniformly continuous because it has a bounded derivative. It is not difficult. Let $f(0):=1$ and write $f(x)=1+\int_0^x f'(y)\, dy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about *uniform continuity*. "Equicontinuity" refers to families of functions: All members of the family should behave equally nicely.

Here we are given the function
$${\rm sinc}(x):=\left\{\eqalign{{\sin x\over x}\quad&(x\ne0)\cr 1\qquad&(x=0)\ .\cr}\right.$$
Note that we can write this function in the form
$${\rm sinc}(x)=\int_0^1\cos(t x)\>dt\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ ,$$
so that
$$\bigl|{\rm sinc}(y)-{\rm sinc}(x)\bigr|\leq\int_0^1\bigl|\cos(ty)-\cos (tx)\bigr|\>dt\leq\int_0^1\bigl|ty-tx\bigr|dt={1\over2}|y-x|\ .$$
This shows that the ${\rm sinc}$ function is Lipschitz continuous, hence uniformly continuous,  over all of ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: To the proposer: Another method is to show that any continuous $f:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R,$ such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exists,  is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x)=0,$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$ Clearly $f(x)=(\sin x)/x$ satisfies these criteria.

Comment: typo corrected$\,$